# How to tip an Uber driver when the company is covering expenses

Tags: ethics, company-culture, expenses

If an employee is sent somewhere by the boss/company via Uber and they are covering expenses, how should the employee tip the driver?

- Should the employee act as if he is taking his own ride, and tip the same way he normally would, even though it's not his money?
- Should the employee not tip at all because the company is paying for
  travel expenses and a tip is not a necessary travel expense?
- Can the employee tip the driver an astronomical amount because he's
  not losing any money anyway?
- Must the employee ask the boss every time how much he can/should tip,
  or at least ask one time for general guidance?
- Should the employee simply tip the driver from his own pocket?
- Is there any sort of accepted workplace norm regarding this type of
  situation?
- Do companies have official policies about this?
- What are the legal and ethical ramifications of this?
- Would it make a difference if the trips are a rare occurrence or a
  daily activity?

Comment: How often are you taking these work related Uber trips?

Comment: Are you or your company socially obligated to leave any tip at all?

Comment: @Kozaky No more than any rider is.

Comment: @Snow See the edit.

Comment: Related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/28115/should-i-include-tips-gratuities-on-expense-reports?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

For the occasional trip, I would tip approximately out of my own pocket to make things simple (and preventing the finance department from asking me why I'm expensing tips).

For more regular trips, I would ask for guidance from my manager and then follow that advice.

Comment: I meant to include an option of tipping yourself in the question. I will edit it in.

Comment: My employer's policy is that tips are not reimbursable. Whether in a restaurant or to a taxi driver. Also we apply this to contractors that we pay expenses for.